# li tag border bottom too long

Tags: css, html-lists, border

I was trying to mimick this menu thing I keep seeing, I tried this:

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item one</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

ol li:hover {
    border-bottom: 6px solid lightblue;
}
```

but the problem is, because I am keeping a distance betweem each list item, the bottom border will use all of that space, is there a way to keep it to the length of the word(s) and still keep the space in between?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `margin-right` instead of `padding-right`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I do understand your question correctly, but you might try to add `margin-bottom:1px;` to 'ol li', so you regain the space in between the `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the style to an element contained inside the `li`:

```
<ol>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
    <li><span>item one</span></li>
</ol>
```

Then it will underline only the text and not the whole `li`.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/UEN9Q/)

Comment: The solution by @AlexPrinceton obtains the same result and is simpler.